# Electric field between capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, gauss-law

> A parallel-plate capacitor consists of two parallel, conducting plates of area $A$, separated by a distance $d$. Each carries a charge of magnitude $Q$; positive on one, negative on the other. Using Gauss' Law, find the electric field between the plates. (Indicate direction and magnitude.)

**My solution:**
$E_1 A = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0 \pi r^2}$;
$E_2 A = \frac{-Q}{\epsilon_0 \pi r^2}$ (using a Gaussian cylinder)

Now, then $E = \frac{2Q}{\epsilon_0 \pi r^2}$.

I feel that I may have not taken some concepts into account. Namely, the distance d between the plates...
I would definitely appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: wouldnt strictly call that field-theory more electrostatics. Anyway, your solution makes little sense (maybe you meant sth else)  $|EA| = |Q|/\epsilon$  the area is the crossection, i.e. A (you draw a little rectangular box around one of the plates, not a cylinder, wrong symmetry). You do this only for one plate (how else with a closed surface, be careful re signs (surface normal parallel/antiparallel to field?)) . The distance does enter if you write it as a function of the voltage (not the charge) as field is nothing but voltage per distance: $E=V/d$. Both results allow to determine capacity

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the $\vec{E}$ field in a parallel plate is **independent** of distance from the plate. This works because of the assumption $d \ll$ length of plate (thus, we can ignore side effects of the plate). And as Bort pointed out, it is the Voltage $V$ that scales linearly with respect to distance from the plate, while $\vec{E}$ will remain constant.